# Negamax implementation doesn't appear to work with tic-tac-toe

Tags: c++, algorithm, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I've implemented Negamax as it can be found on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negamax), which includes alpha/beta pruning.

However, it seems to favor a losing move, which is an invalid result to my knowledge.

The game is Tic-Tac-Toe, I've abstracted most of the game play so it should be rather easy to spot an error within the algorithm.

```
#include <list>
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>

//#define DEBUG 1

using namespace std;

struct Move {
    int row, col;

    Move(int row, int col) : row(row), col(col) { }
    Move(const Move& m) { row = m.row; col = m.col; }
};

struct Board {
    char player;
    char opponent;
    char board[3][3];

    Board() { }

    void read(istream& stream) {
        stream >> player;
        opponent = player == 'X' ? 'O' : 'X';

        for(int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
            for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
                char playa;

                stream >> playa;
                board[row][col] = playa == '_' ? 0 : playa == player ? 1 : -1;
            }
        }
    }

    void print(ostream& stream) {
        for(int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
            for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
                switch(board[row][col]) {
                    case -1:
                        stream << opponent;
                        break;

                    case 0:
                        stream << '_';
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        stream << player;
                        break;

                }
            }
            stream << endl;
        }
    }

    void do_move(const Move& move, int player) {
        board[move.row][move.col] = player;
    }

    void undo_move(const Move& move) {
        board[move.row][move.col] = 0;
    }

    bool isWon() {
        if (board[0][0] != 0) {
            if (board[0][0] == board[0][1] &&
                    board[0][1] == board[0][2])
                return true;

            if (board[0][0] == board[1][0] &&
                    board[1][0] == board[2][0])
                return true;
        }

        if (board[2][2] != 0) {
            if (board[2][0] == board[2][1] &&
                    board[2][1] == board[2][2])
                return true;

            if (board[0][2] == board[1][2] &&
                    board[1][2] == board[2][2])
                return true;
        }

        if (board[1][1] != 0) {
            if (board[0][1] == board[1][1] &&
                    board[1][1] == board[2][1])
                return true;

            if (board[1][0] == board[1][1] &&
                    board[1][1] == board[1][2])
                return true;

            if (board[0][0] == board[1][1] &&
                    board[1][1] == board[2][2])
                return true;

            if (board[0][2] == board [1][1] &&
                    board[1][1] == board[2][0])
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    list<Move> getMoves() {
        list<Move> moveList;

        for(int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
            for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
                if (board[row][col] == 0)
                    moveList.push_back(Move(row, col));

        return moveList;
    }
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream& stream, Board& board) {
    board.print(stream);
    return stream;
}

istream& operator>> (istream& stream, Board& board) {
    board.read(stream);
    return stream;
}

int evaluate(Board& board) {
    int score = board.isWon() ? 100 : 0;

    for(int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
        for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
            if (board.board[row][col] == 0)
                score += 1;

    return score;
}

int negamax(Board& board, int depth, int player, int alpha, int beta) {
    if (board.isWon() || depth <= 0) {
#if DEBUG > 1
        cout << "Found winner board at depth " << depth << endl;
        cout << board << endl;
#endif
        return player * evaluate(board);
    }

    list<Move> allMoves = board.getMoves();

    if (allMoves.size() == 0)
        return player * evaluate(board);

    for(list<Move>::iterator it = allMoves.begin(); it != allMoves.end(); it++) {
        board.do_move(*it, -player);
        int val = -negamax(board, depth - 1, -player, -beta, -alpha);
        board.undo_move(*it);

        if (val >= beta)
            return val;

        if (val > alpha)
            alpha = val;
    }

    return alpha;
}

void nextMove(Board& board) {
    list<Move> allMoves = board.getMoves();
    Move* bestMove = NULL;
    int bestScore = INT_MIN;

    for(list<Move>::iterator it = allMoves.begin(); it != allMoves.end(); it++) {
        board.do_move(*it, 1);
        int score = -negamax(board, 100, 1, INT_MIN + 1, INT_MAX);
        board.undo_move(*it);

#if DEBUG
        cout << it->row << ' ' << it->col << " = " << score << endl;
#endif

        if (score > bestScore) {
            bestMove = &*it;
            bestScore = score;
        }
    }

    if (!bestMove)
        return;

    cout << bestMove->row << ' ' << bestMove->col << endl;

#if DEBUG
    board.do_move(*bestMove, 1);
    cout << board;
#endif

}

int main() {
    Board board;

    cin >> board;
#if DEBUG
    cout << "Starting board:" << endl;
    cout << board;
#endif

    nextMove(board);
    return 0;
}
```

Giving this input:

```
O
X__
___
___
```

The algorithm chooses to place a piece at 0, 1, causing a guaranteed loss, do to this trap(nothing can be done to win or end in a draw):

```
XO_
X__
___
```

I'm pretty sure the game implementation is correct, but the algorithm should be aswell.

**EDIT:** Updated `evaluate` and `nextMove`.

**EDIT2:** Fixed first problem, there still seem to be bugs though

Comment: Note that this is a losing position for X, so (2,0) is *not* a better move than (1,0).

Comment: @Beta: umm..., no it isn't.  Played tic-tac-toe much?  X must go at (2,0) to block, then O must go at (1,0) to block, then X must go at (1,2) to block, then no one wins.

Comment: @KeithRandall, [facepalm] never mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `evaluate` function counts the empty spaces, and does not recognize a winning board.

**EDIT:**
There's also a relatively minor problem in `nextMove`. The line should be

```
int score = -negamax(board, 0, -1, INT_MIN + 1, INT_MAX);
```

Fix that (and `evaluate`), and the code chooses the right move.

**EDIT:**

This fixes it:

```
if (board.isWon() || depth <= 0) {
#if DEBUG > 1
  cout << "Found winner board at depth " << depth << endl;
  cout << board << endl;
#endif
  return -100;                                                      
}
```

Almost all of these problems stem from not being clear about the meaning of `score`. It is from the point of view of `player`. If `negamax` is evaluating the position of player 1, and player 1 cannot win, the score should be low (e.g. -100); if `negamax` is evaluating the position of player -1, and player -1 cannot win, the score should be low (e.g. -100). If `evaluate()` can't distinguish the players, then returning a score of `player * evaluate(board)` is just wrong.

Comment: I have fixed the code, as you suggested, however, I still get the same result. I've updated the code to reflect the changes.

Comment: @GeorgeJiglau,  `if (board.isWon()) {score *= 100;}` What's 0*100?

Comment: I've fixed `evaluate` again, however, that only should have affected games that were won by the last move, it does not affect the current test-case.

Comment: Awesomeness! I didn't really figure out evaluate should evaluate the board from the player's perspective, instead of from a global perspective. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`isWon` returns true for both a win or a loss of the player.  That can't be helping.

Comment: It does not matter, checking if there was a win means the current move produced a game end, thus, there is no need to check further moves.

Comment: But the score returned by negamax needs to be different somehow for a win or a loss.  Either `isWon` or `evaluate` needs to incorporate that tidbit of information...

Comment: I've incorporated this semantic in the evaluation function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be something funny with the use of player.

Your toplevel loop calls "board.do_move(*it, 1);" then calls negamax with player=1.

Then negamax will call "board.do_move(*it, player);", so it looks like the first player is effectively getting 2 moves.

Comment: Oh, right you are! Thank you! Also, in the top-level loop, should I assign the score as the negation of negamax?